# animate a slab out of view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-relativelayout

I have a slab made with a RelativeLayout where height is wrap_content (about `40dp`) and width is match_parent. I want to animate the slab so that it gets smaller and smaller as it slides off the screen to the right. I have the following code, but it's not working.

res/anim/slab_animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <scale android:fromXScale="1.0" android:fromYScale="1.0"
          android:toXScale="0.0" android:toYScale="0.0" 
          android:duration="7000" android:fillBefore="false" />
   <translate android:fromXDelta="-200" android:fromYDelta="-200"
          android:duration="7000" />
</set>
```

in Java class:

```
Animation slabAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slab_animation);
mySlabView.startAnimation(slabAnim);
```

Comment: Which result are you getting? Maybe the slab is getting scaled but no translating?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're missing params `toXDelta` param on your `translate` animation, and that you only want an horizontal translation.-

```
<translate android:fromXDelta="-200" 
           android:toXDelta="400" 
           android:duration="7000" />
```